# Filtering sites on Android HNQ widget

Tags: feature-request, android-app, hot-questions, android-app-widgets

I would appreciate some options to customize the Android widget a bit, especially filtering out specific networks.

I really like that I'm getting interesting questions from networks I haven't been active on to broaden my knowledge in fields I'm not familiar with. My problem is that despite all the great interesting networks, I would like to filter out for example "Science fiction & Fantasy" because, to be honest, personally, I don't give a damn about Star Wars, etc. Seeing such questions makes me less excited about the widget.

Besides, I would also set some networks to display more questions than just the "Top hot question".